# Working of ListView Adapter on Adding Item

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am new to the android development and have got a doubt about the working of `setAdapter` and `ListView`.

My `MainActivity.java` looks like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button generate_btn;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arr;
    private Random rand_generator;
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            arr.add(i);
        }
        generate_btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            arr.add(i + 100);
        }
```

As we can see above that I have two for loops, the first one adds integers till 5 to the `ArrayList<Integer> arr` and then I am calling the `setAdapter` on the `listView`. Till here `arr` only contains the integers till 5.

In the second loop, I am adding integers from 100 to 104 but not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I expected that the rendered result will contain `TextViews` till 5 only since I have set the adapter when `arr` was having elements till 5. But to my surprise, the result was having `TextViews` of integers added in the second for loop also.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`Adapter` maintains the reference to `arr`. So even if we are updating the `ArrayList` after the `setAdapter(..)` the size is getting updated accordingly and it can be cross-checked by putting a print statement of `arr.size()` in `getView(..)` method of a `CustomAdapter`.

`getView(..)` is called by `listView` in various cases till `adapter.getItemCount()` is more than the internal integer pointer.